# Java Efficiency - Point vs. Coordinates

Tags: java, performance, animation, 2d, point

Is there a big difference in efficiency when using `Point2D` instead of `double` x and y values?

I'm working on a program that has many circles moving around the screen.  They each start at one point, and get closer and closer to their destinations (finally, they stop).

Using methods like `.getCurrentLocation().GetY()` (where `currentLocation` is a `Point2D`), I'm experiencing slow performance with any large number of entities.

I don't want to go back and revise all my code for no reason, so I'm asking if I would see a significant performance increase from just storing X and Y `double` coordinates instead of using `Points`.

Comment: When running a profiler, what is taking the most actual time?    There are a number of different possibilities here...

Comment: You'll see some improvement, but I think that's not the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on whether you constantly create new points. If not, i.e. you reuse the existing ones, you shouldn't get a big performance difference.

What is costly about objects in most cases is not the storage but the object creation.

However, as suggested by aix, try and use a profiler to find the real performance bottlenecks.

Comment: Great point about modifying existing points instead of creating new points.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you should use a profiler to find out what's causing the poor performance. I use [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/overview/index.jsp), but there are others.

**If `Point2D` is indeed the problem**, you could represent your points as two `double` arrays, one for all `x` coordinates and one for all `y` coordinates. This is likely to be a lot faster than keeping a collection of `Point2D` objects.